# Erro 403 dependendo da situação

Tags: php, ckeditor

Tenho uma pagina onde posto e edito materia post.php, uso o ckeditor nela na parte de conteudo, porem está acontecendo o seguinte: quando insiro um codigo `<iframe scr="yotube.bla.bla.bla" ... </iframe>` apos o submit ele vai para a pagina:

> You don't have permission to access post_envia.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Protected by COMODO WAF
>   Server at site.com.br Port 80

O interessante é se eu nao coloco iframe, é concluido com sucesso, alguma luz sobre o que pode ser ?

ja tentei, `$conteudo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['conteudo'])`, porem sem sucesso

Comment: Erro 403 é erro de permissão. Provavelmente está usando um iframe de uma página que precisa de autenticação em uma página em domínio diferente.

Comment: no caso estou usando apenas o codigo iframe do youtube normal

Comment: Agora que notei. Você está usando COMODO WAF. Ele bloqueia certas coisas. Precisa adicionar uma regra pra permitir o post com a tag iframe pelo jeito

Comment: realemnte o problema e o iframe